# Editing a file, adding the change to branch A, and the change is visible in branch B

Tags: git

I have two branches: `master` and `branch_b`. I edited a file using Notepad, saved it and added the change to `branch_b`. I.e.:

```
git checkout branch_b
... edit the file
git add -A
```

I then switched back to `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

I looked at the file on the disk, and saw the change I made while being in `branch_b`.

I was also able to `commit` this change as a change to `master`, even though it was added to `branch_b` (what?).

Should this be happening? Shouldn't `add`ing a change to a specific branch leave the state of the file in the other branches the way it was before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding is *not* committing.

Unless a change is **committed**, that change does not become part of any branch. Adding simply makes the changes *staged* for the next commit. Git does not care on which branch you do the commit. It will commit the *staged* changes onto wherever the HEAD is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Before moving to master branch you must have to commit that changes and push that changes to the branch.